# Autoresizing according to devices

Tags: ios, autolayout

From the starting till the end, how do I initialise an UIImageView programmatically, and constraint the frame to the middle of the screen so that when the devices with different width is used, it is still in the middle.

Another words, how do I autolayout my outlets programmatically? With constraints?

For example, my background image is required to be in full screen, with constraining all the sides with constant 0. What is tthe coding basically from the start until the end?

Comment: You shouldn't really ask for the code "from the start until the end". That's not what this site is about. You should try and understand the docs first and show us your attempt at trying to achieve your end goal. You won't learn as much by people just giving you code.

Comment: Actually I did try. I just didn't want to confuse anyone what I was doing.  Anyway thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
{
    UIView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image"]];
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:YOUR_HEIGHT_CONSTANT]];
    [imageView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:1 constant:YOUR_WIDTH_CONSTANT]];

    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:imageView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0]];
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Comment: CGRect landscapeframe = landscape.frame;
    landscapeframe.origin.x = 0;
    landscapeframe.origin.y = 0;

Comment: [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    landscape.frame = landscapeframe;  
    [UIView commitAnimations];

Comment: I wanted to animate "landscape"  downwards when the game start and permanently disappear until the game restarted. Somehow after it has disappear from the screen, it will appear back on the screen. I'm not sure what do I need to do?

Comment: Did my post answer your question? if so, mark it as resolved and ask new question, about your animation problem

Comment: Thank you, it does. Sorry, I'm new to stack.